# How could I move randomly this triangle? p5.js

Tags: random, jquery-animate, p5.js

Since few days I try to animate my triangle, I want to move it randomly on my canvas. All of my tests were a failure so if you have some tips I am open to it!

I wish my triangle move on x and y axis randomly like a free electron and in the future I would like to have other triangles that move randomly and when they touch each other they bounce but it's another step!

My code:

```js
    let x = 50;
    let y = 200;
    let y1 = 100;
    let y2 = 200
    let x1 = 100;
    let x2= 150;
    let speed = 5;
    let startColor;
    let endColor;
    let amt = 0;
    
    
    function setup() {
        startColor = color("hsl(172, 100%, 50%)");
        endColor = color("hsl(335, 100%, 50%)");
        createCanvas(windowWidth, 800);
        frameRate(45);
    
    }
    
    function draw() {
        colorMode(RGB);
        background(252, 238, 10);
        shape(); // Appel de la function shape
        bounce();// appel de la fonction bounce
    
    
    }
    
    function bounce() {
        x = x + speed;
        x1 = x1 + speed;
        x2 = x2 + speed;
        y = y + speed
        y1 = y1 + speed
        y2 = y2 + speed
        if (x2 > windowWidth || x < 0) {
            speed = speed * -1;
        }
    }
    
    function shape() {
    
        if (amt >= 1) {
            amt = 0;
            let tmpColor = startColor;
            startColor = endColor;
            endColor = tmpColor;
        }
        amt += 0.01;
        let colorTransition = lerpColor(startColor, endColor, amt);
        noStroke();
        fill(colorTransition);
        triangle(x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have a code working to make your triangle always move in the same direction. What you could do to make it random is to change the speed you are using:

For now each call to `bounce` moves the triangle by `speed` pixels. So if in `draw()` before calling `shape()` you add the following, triangle will begin to randomly move by a small amount:

```
speed = map(random(), 0, 1, -5, 5);
```

There are tons of different ways to do it, here we have making use of processing's `random()` to generate a number between `0` and `1` and `map()` to get a value between `-5` and `5`.

Now the issue is that you have only one type of speed and you apply to both axis `x` and `y`. What you want is probably to have `speedX` and `speedY` with two different values applied to both component of your position.

Once you try to do that you'll realize that having two variables for `speedX` and `speedY` is not very convenient and that you'd rather have one variable for your position with two component `x` and `y` and same for your speed. This way you'll be able to do `position = position + speed`. This requires that you refactor your code to use a more object oriented paradigm. To learn how to do that, one of the best resources online is the "Nature of Code" playlist by [The coding train](https://www.youtube.com/c/TheCodingTrain/playlists) youtube channel.

Comment: Thanks for your time and for the tips ! I will share my code when it works with the help you gave to me

Answer (score 0):

I work every day and i followed all your advices and now this is what i have product, thanks for all !!

```
let triangle1;
let triangle2;
let triangle3;
let triangle4;
let triangle5;
let speedX;
let speedY;
let startColor;
let endColor;
let amt = 0;


function setup() {
    startColor = color("hsl(172, 100%, 50%)");
    endColor = color("hsl(335, 100%, 50%)");
    createCanvas(windowWidth, 800);
    //creer notre triangle
    triangle1 = new Triangles(200, 100, 0, 4);
    triangle2 = new Triangles(100, 50, 2, 0);
    triangle3 = new Triangles(50, 200, -1, 4);
    triangle4 = new Triangles(250, 400, 4, 4);
    triangle5 = new Triangles(150, 500, 0, 2);

}

function draw() {
    colorMode(RGB);
    background(252, 238, 10);
    triangle1.show();
    triangle1.move();
    triangle2.show();
    triangle2.move();
    triangle3.show();
    triangle3.move();
    triangle4.show();
    triangle4.move();
    triangle5.show();
    triangle5.move();

}


class Triangles {
    //configuration de l'objet
    constructor(triX, triY, speedX, speedY){
        this.x = triX;
        this.y = triY;
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;

    }

    show(){
        if (amt >= 1) {
            amt = 0;
            let tmpColor = startColor;
            startColor = endColor;
            endColor = tmpColor;
        }
        amt += 0.01;
        let colorTransition = lerpColor(startColor, endColor, amt);
        noStroke();
        fill(colorTransition);
        noStroke();
        triangle(this.x, this.y, this.x + 25, this.y + 40, this.x -25, this.y + 40);
    }
    move(){
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;

        if(this.x > width || this.x < 0){

            this.speedX *= -1;

        }
        if(this.y > height || this.y < 0){

            this.speedY = this.speedY * -1;

        }
    }
}
```